# CMake: how to expose sub-project's private headers for tests?

Tags: cmake

I have a sub-project in my project's tree, added via `add_subdirectory( subproject )`. On the same level, there are some tests, also added via `add_subdirectory( tests )`. The subproject exposes its public headers (via `target_set_include_directories( subproject PUBLIC ... )`, however, the tests need to access private headers (those added via PRIVATE keyword). Is there any more correct way to do this than just to specify `include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/subproject/private/)` in tests' CMakeLists.txt? I had the idea to add a separate target subproject_testing which exposes private headers, but run into problems with precompiled headers and parallel compilation of dependencies (the subproject needs a non-CMake library compiled during configure step via add_custom_command, and when two targets try to run this build at the same time, it fails for one of them).